# Internal Server Error while trying to get active filtered data

Tags: jquery

I want to get the active data and show it in a grid but when I click on the search button I am getting an internal server error in the second line.

```js
$("#btnSearch").click(function() {
  var isActive = $("#IsActive").prop('checked');
  var postData = {
    'empid': guid,
    'page': 1,
    'rows': 50,
    'sidx': 'Yes',
    'sord': 'asc',
    'IsActive': isActive
  };

  $("#EmployeeAccList").jqGrid('setGridParam', {
    'url': '/HRMS/Employee/EmployeeAccList'
  });
  
  $("#EmployeeAccList").jqGrid('setGridParam', {
    'postData': postData
  });
  
  $("#EmployeeAccList").trigger("reloadGrid");
});
```

Comment: An internal server error will be coming from your server side code, not the client side Javascript. Therefore the code you've placed in the question isn't relevant to the problem and we can't help you debug it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.